# one path level up using ../ in google colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, filepath

I have to work on a GitHub code, code of a paper, which is huge, so it would take a lot time to change it manually.
**update question:**
the code contains several python files and modules in deferent directories, something like this:

```
algorithm1/
├─ data/
├─ model/
├─ some_func.py
├─ evaluate.py
├─ train.py
utils/
├─ data/
├─ model/
├─ some_helper.py
├─ plot.py
├─ anything_else.py
```

and I am trying to train/evaluate my model like this:

```
%run /content/drive/algorithm1/train.py
```

**end of update**

**the problem** is in some files, it uses `../` to reference to the parent directory (for example: `save_dir='../dir_A/dir_B/dir_C`)
but colab does not recognize it:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../dir_A/dir_B/dir_C/file.csv'
```

I know I can fix it by changing it like this:

```
save_dir='/content/drive/dir_D/dir_A/dir_B/dir_C/'
```

but it would take too much time, since every time parent directory (i.e. `dir_D`) would be different. and this statement `save_dir='../dir1/dir2` would be different (for example `sys.path.append('../dir_E/')` or `os.path.join('..', 'dir_F')` etc.

is there anyway to make colab recognize `../` or edit them faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okey I got it. there was three problems in my tries.
first I was trying to run the python scripts like this:

```
%matplotlib inline
%run my_python_file.py
```

now it replaced `%run` with `!python` and it worked

the second problem was that in each file, I must add this to let interpreter search the right place ( in my code, there are some modules in one level up path ):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
```

third, I must change my directory next to the python file I was trying to run, and I was addressing to the file directly, so I changed :

```
%run /content/drive/dir1/dir2/my_python_file.py
```

to

```
os.chdir('/content/drive/dir1/dir2/')
!python my_python_file.py
```

I updated the question to reduce misunderstanding in the later references